# System memory is lower than installed

Tags: ram

I have a relatively old laptop, Dell Inspiron 5559 with 16 GiB of RAM. It had Windows 10 installed and it showed the whole amount of RAM but I decided to install ubuntu 64 bit on it. I installed 20.04, then upgraded to 20.10 and now to 21.04. It only shows a total amount of memory of 2.5 GiB in the configuration window and also as output for `free` command (spanish OS):

```
              total       usado       libre  compartido búfer/caché  disponible
Memoria:       2,5Gi       1,6Gi       108Mi       417Mi       802Mi       256Mi
Swap:          15Gi       893Mi        14Gi
```

`sudo lshw` shows this:

```
     *-memory
          descripción: Memoria de sistema
          id físico: 46
          ranura: Placa de sistema o placa base
          tamaño: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             descripción: SODIMM DDR3 Síncrono 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             producto: M471B1G73EB0-YK0
             fabricante: Samsung
             id físico: 0
             serie: 12151215
             ranura: DIMM A
             tamaño: 8GiB
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             descripción: SODIMM DDR3 Síncrono 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             producto: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB
             fabricante: SK Hynix
             id físico: 1
             serie: 12121212
             ranura: DIMM B
             tamaño: 8GiB
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

I've upgraded the BIOS firmware from 1.7.0 to 1.9.0 but it made no difference.

I don't have an EFI partition so I have UEFI Legacy enabled in the BIOS.

I've read similar issues for other people but not with such a difference in the amount of memory.

memtest86+ runs the tests and shows no errors but it also shows that the total amount of memory is 2.5 GiB.

The laptop has 2 graphic cards. I don't know if this could affect the issue anyhow but they are:

```
        *-pci:0
             descripción: PCI bridge
             producto: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1c
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             versión: f1
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memoria:df200000-df2fffff ioport:c0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                descripción: Display controller
                producto: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
                fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
                versión: 81
                anchura: 64 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
                configuración: driver=radeon latency=0
                recursos: irq:131 memoria:c0000000-cfffffff memoria:df200000-df23ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:df240000-df25ffff
```

and

```
     *-pci
          descripción: Host bridge
          producto: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          fabricante: Intel Corporation
          id físico: 100
          información del bus: pci@0000:00:00.0
          versión: 08
          anchura: 32 bits
          reloj: 33MHz
          configuración: driver=skl_uncore
          recursos: irq:0
        *-display
             descripción: VGA compatible controller
             producto: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             versión: 07
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
             recursos: irq:130 memoria:de000000-deffffff memoria:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff
```

Any help to determine the cause of the issue would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: dmidecode output

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0046
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM A
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 12151215
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B1G73EB0-YK0  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V

Handle 0x0048, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0046
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM B
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: SK Hynix
    Serial Number: 12121212
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

EDIT: Adding partition information as requested

```
/dev/sda1 1,0 MB BIOS Boot
/dev/sda2 70 GB Ext4 Linux Filesystem /
/dev/sda3 16 GB Linux Swap
/dev/sda4 500 MB Ext4 Linux Filesystem /boot
/dev/sda5 425 GB Ext4 Linux Filesystem /home
```

BIOS report the whole amount of memory, 16 GB.

Comment: How was it with 20.04 and 20.10?

Comment: I don't remember with 20.04 but it was the same with 20.10

Comment: It is odd, Ubuntu seems to think ram/memory is swap.  Can you open 'disks' or 'gparted' and see what your partitions look like(all of them) and report their sizes and labels, or picture.  What does bios report as ram size?

Comment: @crip659 I'm going to edit the description and add the information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your hardware seems good, but  you platform configuration seems  to be badly handled  by the O/S maybe because a little bit old (2015)

in order to diagnose, can you try this :

- keep *UEFI Legacy* enabled in the BIOS
- activate an option called "memory remap", if available in  your BIOS
- boot from your system installed on hardrive

or

- switch your BIOS in "full UEFI" mode
- boot on a Live Ubuntu 64bits from an USB stick

?

*PS : temporarily, so as to get a fresh O/S configuration or in order to run  in full UEFI mode, you can also boot on a Live Ubuntu 64bits from an USB stick (instead of your harddrive)*

Comment: Thanks giles. UEFI Legacy was already enabled and I don't remember to see any "memory remap" setting but I'll double check.

Comment: Can also try to remove and re-install memory.  Does seem like Ubuntu is not seeing/using all your ram, but is reporting it is there.  Right now the problem looks to be more in ram than Ubuntu, since memtest reported the same.

Comment: No "memory remap" setting in BIOS. If I understand correctly, you want me to disable UEFI legacy (which will make the system not able to start) and use a live ubuntu in order to see if it sees all the ram. I think I can also use a live ubuntu first without disabling UEFI legacy and see if that also sees 2.5 GB and then disable the setting.

Comment: @crip659 I could try to do that after trying with the Live Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello Crip659, I believed that the O/S hardware management (depending on the BIOS settings) could be involved because I do  thought that Memtest was running over an O/S, I mean that even if it is not Ubuntu the impact on Memtest might the same.

Comment: @Spakinz : yes that's my idea, if you boot from a "live ubuntu" (USB) you can tune your BIOS as you like and find out what's going easily (your problem is tricky, you  may need many reboots; you  can also return to BIOS factory settings if you feel confortable with this)

Comment: @gillesgaido booting from ubuntu live 20.04 without disabling UEFI legacy still showed 2.5 GB. Then I disabled UEFI legacy in BIOS and tried to boot ubuntu live again. I got the following error [link](https://ibb.co/yY33z0v). Then tried again with a different boot option (graphical recovery or compatibility or something like that) that seemed not to load the graphic drivers and it worked! It shown 15.5 GB. [link](https://ibb.co/yRhNHvS). So either it has to do with UEFI vs BIOS or with the graphical display. Next thing is to reinstall the system with UEFI support. Hopefully that will do it.

Comment: Great ! If you reinstall it should work as well as it works with the "live ubuntu". Perhaps you will need before to switch the harddrive from MBR to GPT partitions with Gparted or equivalent.

Comment: Here is a live CD with GPARTED in case that it is not included in "Live ubuntu" : [link](https://gparted.org/faq.php)

Comment: Finally reinstalled but it is weird that I have to enable UEFI and also legacy, like a hybrid solution. It didn't work by going full UEFI. Anyway, it is showing 15.5 GB now. Thank you all.

Comment: @spakinz : Happy for you, and thanks a lot for your feedback ! It you encounter any unstability or major issue later on, you can consider also to upgrade your BIOS https://www.dell.com/support/home/es-es/product-support/product/inspiron-15-5559-laptop/drivers ( last version 11-2020 ). The BIOS settings will probably be reset. (PS : note the current version in order to rollback if needed). Regards.